replit’s jupyter notebook bugs for non-macos safari - 403: Forbidden
enter image description herereplit’s jupyter notebook depo: not working at ipad safari / ipad app: “error 403: Forbidden The error was: XSRF cookie does not match POST argument”.
the depo only works for macos safari. for other devices, the error 403 occurs.
